# Any way to merge plugins in RPG maker XP?

Tags: rpg-maker-xp

So I'm trying to merge together 2 mods into one game. One is [Tankentai's SBS](http://www.gdunlimited.net/scripts/rpg-maker-xp/custom-battle-scripts/sideview-battle-system-tankentai-xp) and the other is [Cocoa's UMS](http://www.gdunlimited.net/forums/files/file/63-ccoas-ums-18/).

I'm trying to merge the 2 into one game that includes the battle system from SBS, but the text boxes and whatnot from UMS. Is there any easy way to do this other than combing through all the script lines and copying them one at a time? I've tried to use [this](https://forum.chaos-project.com/index.php?topic=15072.0) but it doesn't seem to do quite what I need it to do.

Comment: I don't think so. But I only say that from a general idea of how mods work. I have not worked with RPGMaker.

Comment: well in rpg maker xp, plugins are made by creating and editing text files. The problem is, the 2 mods I'm trying to use together use alternate variations of the same files.

Comment: Right, that's what I expected. No there is not an easy way to do this. It's not impossible, though. :)

Comment: since one is a Custom Message System and the other is a Custom Battle System, is there a reason why you can't just use both? is one script acting differently when the other is added? is there any errors coming up when they are both used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omg I just figured it out by pure luck. So I was trying to take the battle system and add it to the text system, which was complex. But then I thought to do it in *reverse order* and wow, now I feel stupid. So to do it in reverse order, go into the scripts file of the UMS, and copy the script subfile (idk what to call it) that is named UMS. Then go into the other game with the SBS, go into the scripts file, and paste the UMS subscript at the bottom of the subscripts list. Then copy the graphics from the UMS game into the graphics folder for the SBS game, and everything works perfectly!